# How to find default supported C++ standard by g++ compiler in cmake

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake

I saw many threads regarding how to enable certain C++ standard e.g.

```
add_definitions("-std=c++14")
```

and

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

But how to find which standard by default g++ compiler following while compiling code ?

Comment: Have cmake use the compiler to try and compile a small program that uses C++-some version only features.

Comment: Or check the version of the compiler and match it to known versions of that compiler that support some version of the C++ standard

Answer (score 0):

`add_definitions("-std=c++14")` is not the correct way to enable C++14. The right way either the second one you mentioned: `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)`, or `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14")`.

`add_definitions` is for macro definitions, equivalent to `#define` in your source code.

About your question, it's bad practice to depend on the default version of C++ in your compiler. Even Visual Studio now defines the standard you want to use, which is a new thing in VS. Standards are made to solve this problem **by having them specified**. So, in your project, you define the target standard, and you define it in your make file. You should not expect your code to work on all C++ standards.

Comment: Teach me about particle physics please

Comment: @The Quantum , thanks for very useful answer, my question was, If I dnt set compiler standard flag (bad practice accepted), by default which standard g++ following ? How to find this. One is too use documentation but I want to do runtime.

Comment: @SombreroChicken Check out my Stack Exchange Physics account.

Comment: @TonyParker I don't know of a way to do this. I don't expect it to be possible. There's a way around this, but it'll ruin the possibility to cross-compile. You create a small program that uses the macros that tell you the C++ version, then you print them, and parse them in cmake while compiling the target program.

Comment: ... and the macro to use would be `__cplusplus`. For the possible values (so far!), see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#Predefined_macros

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing an **application**, then you should not adjust your code based on available compiler version, instead you should specify which compiler standard your code *requires*:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

If you're building a code **library** that is meant to be used in different contexts, use compiler [feature detection](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html#conditional-compilation-options) and conditional compilation. For example:

```
write_compiler_detection_header(
  FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/compiler_features.h"
  PREFIX Foo
  COMPILERS GNU
  FEATURES
    cxx_variadic_templates
)
```

And then:

```
#include "compiler_features.h"
#if Foo_COMPILER_CXX_VARIADIC_TEMPLATES
#  include "with_variadics/interface.h"
#else
#  include "no_variadics/interface.h"
#endif
```

This is especially useful with compilers like MSVC which have many features from C++17 while also lacking some basic features from C++11 (e.g. expression SFINAE).

CMake has built-in [detectors](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/prop_gbl/CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES.html#prop_gbl:CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES) for many popular C++ features.

---

PS. If you're really curious, G++ up to 5.0 uses by default `gnu++98` standard, and from 6.0 `gnu++14` (GNU dialect of -std=c++14).